# Java Silent PDF(Label) Printer

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I'm a Student and Need to create a silten print function wish is able to print PDF. This Need to be based on Java.

I searched on Google and found a code which prints without Dialog.
But it just prints right if the source is a  `.txt` file.

If I try to print a PDF file with this function i'll get very strange characters printed.

Now I'd like to ask why this happens and is there a way to fix it.

```
package org.pack.mypack.jsf;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.Size2DSyntax;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize;

public class PrintJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintJob print = new PrintJob();


    }

    public PrintJob() {
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, null);
        FileInputStream psStream = null;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = null;
        aset =  new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        aset.add(MediaSize.findMedia(2, 2, Size2DSyntax.INCH));

        try {
            psStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\myUser\\test\\test.pdf");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) {
            ffne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (psStream == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (services.length > 0) {
            PrintService myService = null;
            for (PrintService service : services) {
                System.out.println(service.getName());
                if (service.getName().contains("PrinterName")) {
                    myService = service;
                    break;
                }
            }
            DocPrintJob printJob = myService.createPrintJob();
            Doc document = new SimpleDoc(psStream, flavor, null);
            try {

                printJob.print(document, aset);
            } catch (PrintException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No PDF printer available.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this for my previous work and I can ensure that it's a little nightmare without using a library (and I hope that your PDF isn't password protected without knowing the pass).

I used the [Apache PDFBox library](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).

There are a lot of example over the web on how to use it in silent mode

Comment: Thanks alot, u made my life easier :D